# How to add .children method to element[ i ] inside if statement?

Tags: javascript

I want all buttons with the number inside have attribute `data-number`.

I'm on the learning stages. Can you please also give me the solution with the explanation?

```js
const calculatorFooter = document.querySelector('.calculator-footer');
const calculatorButtons = document.querySelector('.calculator-footer__button');
// add attribute data-number to numbers 1-9
let buttonNumber = calculatorFooter.children;
let buttonAtribute = calculatorButtons;
for (i = 0; i < buttonNumber.length; i++) {
  if (buttonNumber[i].innerText.trim() <= 9) {
    buttonNumber[i]. ** children ** .setAttribute('data-number', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-footer">
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>7</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>8</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>9</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>/</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>4</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>5</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>6</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>X</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>1</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>2</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>3</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>+</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>0</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>.</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>DEL</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>-</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>AC</button></div>
  <div class="calculator-footer__button"><button>CE</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet with html? use tools `<>`

Comment: `I'm trying to add .children inside if statement after a buttonNumber[i] = buttonNumber[i].children - is this possible?` what do you mean? Why do you need this?

Comment: buttonNumber is a list of buttons. You want to add attributes to them. Your code is basically already doing that, however you're setting all button's attribute to a blank string. Also, you can simply do `buttonNumber[i].dataset.number = i;` Or are you trying to create those buttons in your code?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini no html , please see the rest of the code

Comment: I want all buttons with the number inside have attribute data-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `querySelectorAll` to select all element then `forEach` it and see if button text is in array(just value 0-9), if yes add `data-number` into element like:

```js
//let calculator-footer__button data array
let calculatorButtonData = [{
    symbol: '7'
  },
  {
    symbol: '8'
  },
  {
    symbol: '9'
  },
  {
    symbol: '/'
  },
  {
    symbol: '4'
  },
  {
    symbol: '5'
  },
  {
    symbol: '6'
  },
  {
    symbol: 'X'
  },
  {
    symbol: '1'
  },
  {
    symbol: '2'
  },
  {
    symbol: '3'
  },
  {
    symbol: '+'
  },
  {
    symbol: '0'
  },
  {
    symbol: '.'
  },
  {
    symbol: 'DEL'
  },
  {
    symbol: '-'
  },
  {
    symbol: 'AC'
  },
  {
    symbol: 'CE'
  },
  {
    symbol: '='
  }
];

const calculatorFooter = document.querySelector('.calculator-footer');
let calculatorButtonsInfo = calculatorButtonData.map(function(buttonData) {
  return '<div class="calculator-footer__button">' + '<button>' + buttonData.symbol + '</button>' + '</div>';
});
calculatorFooter.innerHTML = calculatorButtonsInfo.join('\n');
let buttonNumber = calculatorFooter.querySelectorAll('.calculator-footer__button');
const arr = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
buttonNumber.forEach((el) => {
  let button = el.querySelector('button');
  if (arr.includes(button.innerText.trim())) {
    button.setAttribute('data-number', button.innerText.trim());
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='calculator-footer'></div>
```

---

Another solution is change `object` and add directly `data-number` into map and return empty `data-number` if is not number like:

```js
//let calculator-footer__button data array
let calculatorButtonData = [{
    symbol: '7', datanumber: '7'
  },
  {
    symbol: '8', datanumber: '8'
  },
  {
    symbol: '9', datanumber: '9'
  },
  {
    symbol: '/', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: '4', datanumber: '4'
  },
  {
    symbol: '5', datanumber: '5'
  },
  {
    symbol: '6', datanumber: '6'
  },
  {
    symbol: 'X', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: '1', datanumber: '1'
  },
  {
    symbol: '2', datanumber: '2'
  },
  {
    symbol: '3', datanumber: '3'
  },
  {
    symbol: '+', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: '0', datanumber: '0'
  },
  {
    symbol: '.', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: 'DEL', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: '-', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: 'AC', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: 'CE', datanumber: ''
  },
  {
    symbol: '=', datanumber: ''
  }
];

const calculatorFooter = document.querySelector('.calculator-footer');
let calculatorButtonsInfo = calculatorButtonData.map(function(buttonData) {
  return '<div class="calculator-footer__button">' + '<button data-number="'+buttonData.datanumber+'">' + buttonData.symbol + '</button>' + '</div>';
});
calculatorFooter.innerHTML = calculatorButtonsInfo.join('\n');
```

```html
<div class='calculator-footer'></div>
```

Comment: @Paul C i change now code and data-number will add to button instead of divs ( i didn't see)

Comment: @ Simone , tank you very much for your time and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can access A HTMLElement attribute from the **dataset** property

example:

```
// HTML: <button data-number="3" />
const button = document.querySelector('#my-button');

button.dataset.number // "3"
```

So your code will be:

```
 let buttonNumber = calculatorFooter.children;
 let buttonAtribute = calculatorButtons;
 for (i = 0; i < buttonNumber.length; i++) {
   if (buttonNumber[i].innerText.trim() <= 9) {
    // if your button have 'data-buttonNumber' attribute
     const buttonAttribute = buttonNumber[i].dataset.buttonNumber
     buttonNumber[i].setAttribute('data-number', buttonAttribute);
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.

my <buttons> dont have ID attribute and I'm tryng achieve this wothout it.
Is there any other way ?
Also your code gives me and error "unexpected end of input"

Something like. scan trought the array, detect all the numbers add attribure.